# Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"

Tags: postgresql, ansible

I am provisioning a 'Precise64' Ubuntu machine via Ansible, I am encountering an error when ensuring that the database is in fact created. I am using most of https://github.com/jcalazan/ansible-django-stack

```
- name: Install PostgreSQL
  apt: name={{ item }} update_cache={{ update_apt_cache }} state=installed
  with_items:
    - postgresql
    - postgresql-contrib
    - python-psycopg2
  tags: packages

- name: Ensure the PostgreSQL service is running
  service: name=postgresql state=started enabled=yes

- name: Ensure database is created
  sudo_user: postgres
  postgresql_db: name={{ db_name }}
                 encoding='UTF-8'
                 lc_collate='en_US.UTF-8'
                 lc_ctype='en_US.UTF-8'
                 template='template0'
                 state=present
```

However, when arriving to the last task, I get this error:

> failed: [default] => {"failed": true, "playbook": "vagrant.yml",
>   "role": "db", "task": "Ensure database is created"} msg: unable to
>   connect to database: could not connect to server: No such file or
>   directory     Is the server running locally and accepting     connections on
>   Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
>
> FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

Comment: "/var/run/postgresql>/.s.PGSQL.5432" looks weird. are you sure the > should be there?

Comment: thanks for noticing, it was a typo :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue with ansible and vagrant on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Alfonso's answer didn't solve the problem.

I realised that vagrant copies localisation settings from my system (which were not `en_US`) to the virtual one. That caused database creation problem.

Running following shell code before `vagrant up` fixed the problem:

```
export LANGUAGE=en_US
export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
```

That temporarily changes localisation settings so that `en_US` will be copied to virtual system.

Comment: That makes much more sense, I don't know then how I got it working, accepted your answer, sir :)

Answer (score 4):

The answer by @damgad indeed works for me, but since I'm lazy, I don't wanna have to export all of those env vars every time I need to setup Postgresql.

I could put it into my .bash_rc or similar, but I also don't want to have it defined account wide, since the point here is because I have a different locale.

So, using part of the initial answer by @alfonso-perez, I ended up using this two extra tasks, and haven't had to export anything again:

```
- name: Install Language packages
  apt: name=language-pack-en update_cache={{ update_apt_cache }} force=yes state=latest
  tags: packages

- name: Locale (is a b****)
  locale_gen: name={{ item }} state=present
  with_items:
    - en_US
    - en_US.UTF-8
    - pt_BR.UTF-8
    - de_DE.UTF-8

- name: Install PostgreSQL
  apt: name={{ item }} update_cache={{ update_apt_cache }} state=installed
  with_items:
    - postgresql-9.3
    - postgresql-contrib-9.3
    - postgresql-server-dev-9.3
    - python-psycopg2
  tags: packages
```

Answer (score 1):

after some debugging, I got it working by installing the language pack so the postgres daemon doesn't complain about the Locale when starting

```
- name: Install Language packages
  apt: name=language-pack-en update_cache={{ update_apt_cache}} force=yes state=latest
  tags: packages
```